# Getting original position of arraylist for listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, searchview

I was trying to create a search function for listview, and putting the intent activity for the results. However, as the search results appear, the position changed. For example,
original position should be 0,1. But after searched, the results turn the position to 3,4.
I tried finding many solutions for this, but nothing helps. Thanks in advance !

Here the homefragment.java

```
package com.example.testtt;

import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        //define
        RelativeLayout drawerlayouthome;
        ListView list;
        ListViewAdapter adapter;
        SearchView editsearch;
        ArrayList<DoaSearchIndex> arrayList = new ArrayList<DoaSearchIndex>();




        String[] doasearchindex = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.doasearchindex);

        //locatelistview
        list = v.findViewById(R.id.searchlistview);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent;
                switch (i){
                    case 0:
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), firstactivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        getId();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), secondactivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        getId();
                        break;

                }
                list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < doasearchindex.length; i++) {
            DoaSearchIndex doaSearchIndex = new DoaSearchIndex(doasearchindex[i]);

            arrayList.add(doaSearchIndex);
        }

        //pass result to listviewadapter.class

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this.getActivity(), arrayList);

        //binds adapter to listview

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //locatesearchview

        editsearch = v.findViewById(R.id.searchview);

        editsearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
                    list.clearTextFilter();
                    adapter.filter("");
                    list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    adapter.filter(newText);
                    list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        drawerlayouthome = v.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layouthome);
        drawerlayouthome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                editsearch.clearFocus();
            }
        });





        //definingcardview

        CardView test = v.findViewById(R.id.test);
        CardView testcard = v.findViewById(R.id.testcard);

        //setcardviewlistener

        test.setOnClickListener(this);
        testcard.setOnClickListener(this);






        return v;

    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i ;

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.test:
                i = new Intent(getActivity(), test.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
            case R.id.testcard:
                i = new Intent(getActivity(), testcard.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

and ListViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.testtt;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //Declare variables first

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<DoaSearchIndex> doaSearchIndexList = null;
    private ArrayList<DoaSearchIndex> arrayList;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<DoaSearchIndex> doaSearchIndexList) {
        mContext = context;
        this.doaSearchIndexList = doaSearchIndexList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<DoaSearchIndex>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(doaSearchIndexList);
    }
    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return doaSearchIndexList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public DoaSearchIndex getItem(int position) {
        return doaSearchIndexList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.name.setText(doaSearchIndexList.get(position).getDoaSearchIndex());
        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        doaSearchIndexList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            doaSearchIndexList.addAll(arrayList);
        } else {
            for (DoaSearchIndex wp : arrayList) {
                if (wp.getDoaSearchIndex().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    doaSearchIndexList.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    

}
```

and the DoaSearchIndex.java

```
public class DoaSearchIndex {

    private String doaSearchIndex;
    private int originalPosition;

    public DoaSearchIndex(String doaSearchIndex) {
        this.doaSearchIndex = doaSearchIndex;
    }

    public String getDoaSearchIndex() {
        return this.doaSearchIndex;
    }

    private int getPosition() {
        return this.originalPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to use position variable inside ViewHolder class and update it whenever object create from getview...then try to use the position by using viewholder instance in getview....if you need this click then you can use setag and gettag inside view..may help you

Comment: Where do you log these positions in your code?

Comment: @Ghanshyam can you give me an example?

Comment: Could you try out my answer? If you follow along, your positions will be remembered even you search a specific item in the recyclerView. Let me please know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my example `Fragment`:

```
    public class MyDefaultFragment extends Fragment {

    //Default items
    public static ArrayList<MyItem> myItems = new ArrayList<>();

    //Search filter
    public static String filter = "";

    public MyDefaultFragment(){
        //require a empty constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.defaultfragment,container,false);

            //I used a EditText instead of a SearchView
            EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.filterEditText);

            RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext()));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        //Checks for text change
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            filter = editText.getText().toString();
            handler.postDelayed(this,500);

            }
        },500);


            //Updates the Database every second | 1000 millisecond = 1 second
            Handler update = new Handler();
            update.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    new MyDatabase.AsyncTask(MyDatabase.getInstance(getContext())).execute();
                    update.postDelayed(this,1000);
                }
            },1000);

            //Creates a new object in the Adapter.class
            Adapter adapter = new Adapter();
            myItems.clear();


            //example items
            myItems.add(new MyItem(R.drawable.bcn100, "firstActivity"));
            myItems.add(new MyItem(R.drawable.ada100, "secondActivity"));
            myItems.add(new MyItem(R.drawable.cos100, "otherActivity"));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            //Updates the Database on open the Fragment
            new MyDatabase.AsyncTask(MyDatabase.getInstance(getContext())).execute();
            
            //observe the LiveData<List<MyItem>> to an List<MyItem>
            MyItemViewModel myItemViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyItemViewModel.class);
            myItemViewModel.getAllItems().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), adapter::setItems);
            
        return view;
    }
}
```

---

Here is the `Adapter` for the `CardView`:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.CardHolder> {


    //Item list of the Adapter
    public static List<MyItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CardHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                                                                //CardView the name of the layout file smallcard
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.smallcard, parent, false);
        CardHolder smallCardHolder = new CardHolder(itemView);
        return smallCardHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CardHolder holder, int position) {

        //get the item of the position
        MyItem myItem = items.get(position);
        int image = myItem.getMyImage();
        String name = myItem.getMyName();

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(image);
        holder.textViewName.setText(name);

        //onClickListener for the cardView
        if(holder.cardView!= null) {
            holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                openActivity(holder.textViewName.getText().toString());
            });
        }
    }



    //You have to put here the method to open the activitys
    public void openActivity(String name){

        switch (name){

            case "firstActivity":{
                System.out.println("Open firstActivity");
                break;
            } case "secondActivity":{
                System.out.println("Open secondActivity");
                break;
            } case "otherActivity":{
                System.out.println("Open otherActivity");
                break;
            }

            default:
                break;
        }


    }

    //Amount of items
    @Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return items.size();
    }


    public void setItems(List <MyItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    //Card Holder
    class CardHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        private CardView cardView;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView textViewName;

        public CardHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_View);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_Image);
            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_Name);

        }
    }
}
```

---

Here's the `Database` to insert/delete the `CardView`

```
        //If you change the database schema you have to update the current version +1
@Database(entities = {MyItem.class},version = 1)
public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static MyDatabase instance;

    public abstract MyItemDao myItemDao();


    public static synchronized MyDatabase getInstance(Context context){

        //if the instance is null
        if(instance ==  null){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,MyDatabase.class,"my_Database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(callback)
                    .setAutoCloseTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    private static Callback callback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            new AsyncTask(instance).execute();
        }
    };

    // The Async Task is deprecated you can use the Kotlin CoroutineAsyncTask instead of android.os.AsyncTask
    // If you want to change it, this will help you
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68136577/how-to-replace-asynctask-in-this-android-code/68137304#68137304
    public static class AsyncTask extends android.os.AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        MyItemDao myItemDao;

        public AsyncTask(MyDatabase myDatabase){
            this.myItemDao = myDatabase.myItemDao();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            //default Items
            List<MyItem> allDefaultItems = MyDefaultFragment.myItems;


            //Current listed items in the RecyclerView
            List<MyItem> allAdapterItems = Adapter.items;
            String filter = MyDefaultFragment.filter;
            int length = filter.length();


            //Search method
            if(length >0){
                List<MyItem> deleteItems = new ArrayList<>();
                List<MyItem> updateItems = new ArrayList<>();

                allDefaultItems.forEach(myItem -> {
    if(myItem.myName.toLowerCase().startsWith(filter)){
            updateItems.add(myItem);
           }else{
          deleteItems.add(myItem);
        }
    });

                myItemDao.delete(deleteItems);
                myItemDao.insertAll(updateItems);

            }else{
                myItemDao.insertAll(allDefaultItems);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

MyItem:

```
//If you want can change the tableName you have also change the name in the MyItemDao interface
@Entity(tableName = "myTable")
public class MyItem {

    int myImage;


    //A PrimaryKey is require for a Database
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    String myName;

    public MyItem(int myImage,String myName){
        this.myImage = myImage;
        this.myName = myName;
    }

    public int getMyImage() {
        return myImage;
    }

    public void setMyImage(int myImage) {
        this.myImage = myImage;
    }

    public String getMyName() {
        return myName;
    }

    public void setMyName(String myName) {
        this.myName = myName;
    }
}
```

---

`MyItemDao.java`:

```
@Dao
public interface MyItemDao {
    
    //Select all data from myTable
    @Query("Select * From myTable")
    LiveData<List<MyItem>> getAllItems();
    
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAll(List<MyItem> myItems);

    @Delete
    void delete(List<MyItem> myItems);

    @Query("Delete from myTable")
    void deleteAllItems();
}
```

---

Repository:

```
public class MyItemRepository {

    private LiveData<List<MyItem>> allItems;
    private MyItemDao myItemDao;
    
    public MyItemRepository(Application application){

        MyDatabase myDatabase = MyDatabase.getInstance(application);
        myItemDao = myDatabase.myItemDao();
        allItems = myItemDao.getAllItems();
    }
    public void insertAll(List<MyItem> yItems){ new InsertAllItemsAsyncTask(myItemDao).execute(myItems); }

    public void deleteItems(List<MyItem> myItems){
        new DeleteItemListAsyncTask(myItemDao).execute(myItems);
    }

    public void deleteAllItems(){
        new DeleteAllItemsAsyncTask(myItemDao).execute();
    }
    public LiveData<List<MyItem>> getAllItems(){
        return allItems;
    }


    //Async tasks to put the items to the Database
    private static class InsertAllItemsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<MyItem>,Void,Void>{
        MyItemDao myItemDao;

        private InsertAllItemsAsyncTask(MyItemDao myItemDao){
            this.myItemDao = myItemDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<MyItem>... lists) {
            myItemDao.insertAll(lists[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static class DeleteAllItemsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        MyItemDao myItemDao;

        private DeleteAllItemsAsyncTask(MyItemDao myItemDao){
            this.myItemDao = myItemDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            myItemDao.deleteAllItems();
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static class DeleteItemListAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<MyItem>,Void,Void>{
        MyItemDao myItemDao;

        private DeleteItemListAsyncTask(MyItemDao myItemDao){
            this.myItemDao = myItemDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<MyItem>... myItems) {
            myItemDao.delete(myItems[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

`ViewModel`:

```
public class MyItemViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    //LiveData is require for the RoomDatabase
    private LiveData<List<MyItem>> allItems;
    private MyItemRepository myItemRepository;

    public MyItemViewModel(Application application){
        super(application);
        this.myItemRepository = new MyItemRepository(application);
        allItems = myItemRepository.getAllItems();
    }

    public LiveData<List<MyItem>> getAllItems(){
        return allItems;
    }
    public void insertAll(List<MyItem> myItems){
        myItemRepository.insertAll(myItems);
    }

    //deletes a List of items
    public void delete(List<MyItem> myItems){
        myItemRepository.deleteItems(myItems);
    }
    public void deleteAllItems(){
        myItemRepository.deleteAllItems();
    }
}
```

---

`CardView` I called it `smallcard.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/card_View">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/card_Image"
                    android:layout_width="100px"
                    android:layout_height="100px"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/card_Name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
            
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

The test `Fragment.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MyDefaultFragment"
                android:background="#ffffff">

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/filterEditText"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
    />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_below="@id/filterEditText"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

some `build.gradle(Module)` `implementations`:

```
dependencies{

implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.3.1'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
...
}
```

You will find more information as comments in the code.

---

**UPDATE**

In addition I provide you the whole project on [github](https://github.com/User96543169735/AndroidApp). I added different intents after clicking the Cards. It will open the same `Fragment` for the same Card even you are searching and the positions are changed.

Comment: Sorry sir for the late reply, i am trying to figure out the answers. Can you elaborate more on how to use this method? I am sorry for the questions as I am beginner. But really keen to understand it.

Comment: Alright, no worries. Let me name the classes and xml files you need to create and copy the code in it. I suggest to open a new empty project. With the above code you can reproduce the whole project. Then try to understand it with the comments. That would be the best way as a beginner. I tell you when I renamed everything.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Really appreciate it and thank you very much!

Comment: I'm adding new intents by pressing the Cards. You will get a complete functional project to learn from. I will send you a download link. Give me a bit more time.

Comment: At the very end I added the github project, download it and everything is described as good as I could. Analyze and learn. Feel free to mark the question as correct. Cheers!

Comment: Sure ! Thank you sir !

Comment: just a question, if i cleared parts of the text in edit text, it wouldnt show the results of the search, i need to cleared the whole text, input again the search, then the results will be shown. can i make it show the results instead of need to clear the whole text? if can, then how?

Comment: I changed the Database class. In it there is a for-each loop called allDefaultItems.forEach. Would appreciate if you could upvote my main answer. Cheers! :)